# What is the dependency of a Shared Service Provider on Search?

Tags: search, administration, shared-service-provider

Or asked another way, if I manually stop the Office SharePoint Server Search server called OSearch in the Services Control Panel, what in my SSP would break? 
The Technet Deployment guide states the following on [the SSP Dependency on Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx#section3):

- You must start the Office SharePoint
  Server Search service on at least one
  computer that was set up by using the
  Complete option during Setup. This
  service must be started on the
  computer that you want to use as your
  index server and optionally as a
  query server before you can create an
  SSP

Basically, I want to know why that dependency exists and what breaks when search is off.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the only thing to break would be search.  I don't think your SSP would stop functioning for other services.  I'm not entirely sure there is a dependency in the traditional sense of the word.  It's just that if you don't run the service on at least one server then you cannot have a functioning search.  I guess the technet article is assuming that you require search functionality from your SSP.

I would be interested to see if someone has a full answer on this one too.

Comment: There is a dependency for creation. You can't create an SSP without search. But why not? If you could turn it off safely, why make such a hard up-front dependency. I don't think it's as easy as only search will stop working, but that would be nice.